# Yii filter results without relation

Tags: php, yii, model, relational-database

I am using CGridView in Yii which is listing results with some of relations from other models

```
            <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
                'filter' => $model,
                'columns' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'user.name',
                        'header' => Yii::t('app', 'User'),
                        'value' => '!isset($data->user->name) ? Yii::t("app", "Unknown user") : $data->user->name',
                        'type'  => 'raw',
                        'filter' => CHtml::activeTextField($model, 'keyName'),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'visitor.company',
                        'header' => Yii::t('app', 'Company'),
                        'value' => 'isset($data->visit->visitor->company) ? $data->visit->visitor->company : (isset($data->rfid->rfid) ? Yii::t("app", "Company 1") : Yii::t("app", "Unknown company"))',
                        'type'  => 'raw',
                        'filter' => CHtml::activeTextField($model, 'visitorCompany'),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'pass_id',
                        'header' => Yii::t('app', 'Pass'),
                        'value' => '!isset($data->pass_id) ? Yii::t("app", "Massing pass") : "<span class=\"label label-primary\">" . $data->pass_id . "</span>"',
                        'type'  => 'raw',
                    ),
                ),
            )); ?>
```

and there is `isset()` condition which checks if relation exists (otherwise an error occurs)

But now I am looking for a way to filter those results which. For example to write "Unknown" in the filter to get the results without relations in the other table or "Company" to get those without some relation but with another existing relation

Comment: what do you want exactly from this??

Comment: to be able to filter the results without relation in another model

Comment: Probably it helps you, for example redefining your data provider or using virtual fields, giving the role of data preparation to model  http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/32683-searching-and-sorting-on-calculated-values-in-cgridview/